# Why my div is going outside of its parent div?

Tags: html, css

Div with id "message-box" is going outside its parent div "message-container"
I dont understand why?

I used "overflow:auto;" in my css for "message-box". but still its not giving me the desired result. margin left is not working properly when i use "overflow:auto" on "message-box".

**Below is my HTML file:**

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" >  
<title>temp</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="main">

<div id="header">header</div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="user-container">user</div>

    <div id="message-container">
        <div id="message-box">message box</div>
        <div id="text-box"> text box</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Below is my CSS file:**

```
#main{
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 5px;
}

#header{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:30px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#container{
    margin:10px;
    height:32em;
}
#footer{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:30px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#user-container{
    border: 1px solid red;
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    height:32em;    
}
#message-container{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:32em;
    width:100%;

}
#message-box{
    border: 1px solid grey;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:5px;
}
#text-box{
    border:1px solid grey;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:5px;
}
```

please someone help me out here.

Comment: It isn't: http://jsfiddle.net/r1y4oh68/

Comment: Thank you. But see that grey border. It doesn't have any left margin. why is this happening?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/6wj8bqqa/1/

Answer (score 6):

## Quick answer

Your `#message-box` has correct margins all around in relation to the `#message-container` div, but the problem is that both `#message-container` and `#message-box` are overflowing into `#user-container`. Since `#message-box` has the `overflow` property, it is clipped at the exact edge where it overflows into `#user-container`. Since `#message-container` does not have `overflow`, it continues to flow behind the `#user-container` to the edge of the `#container` div. To fix this, add `overflow` to the `#message-container`.

```
#message-container {
  height: 32em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I think what you want here is `overflow: hidden` to clip the overflowing content; `overflow: auto` adds scroll bars to see the overflowing content.

## Explanation

The `float` on `#user-container` is causing the problem. Floats remove an element from the normal document 'flow' (see Normal Document Flow below).

I added background colors to `#user-container`(green) and `#message-container`(blue) so you can see what's happening. If you remove `overflow` from `#text-box` and `#message-box`, you'll see margins are actually working correctly between `#message-box` and `#message-container`. Add them back and you'll see how they get clipped by `#user-container`.

**This is what's happening** http://jsfiddle.net/fmceqbdp/2/

### Normal Document Flow

The DOM has an element hierarchy. The document is the highest level parent (or outermost box), and any element you add is its child. The element's starting position is the upperleft of its parent. If you add another element at the same level (not nested), it is another child of the document and a sibling of the first element. The sibling also wants to be positioned as close as it can to the upperleft of the document, but it gets pushed right by the first element (inline) or to the next line (block). When you nest an element inside that element, the nested element is the child, it is contained inside the parent. It's starting position is the upperleft of its parent element. This is normal document flow. A floated element is removed from this normal flow, so it doesn't push other elements the way it normally would.

### How Floats Behave

Divs are block elements, they push other elements away. However, when you float an element, it removes that element from the normal document flow -- that means its position is invisible to sibling elements (elements at the same level), so they're now positioned in front or behind the floated element as though the floated element doesn't exist. Because you floated `#user-container`, `#message-container` fills the entire `#container` as though `#user-container` is not there.

### How Overflow Works

The element that has the `overflow` property will self-clear from overflowing into other elements. This is why `#message-container` flowed into the space occupied by `#user-container` but its children `#message-box` and `#text-box` with the overflow property had cleared themselves from flowing into the space `#user-container`. Their margins were still relative to their parent `#message-container`, not where they're clipped, which is why it appeared there was no left margin where they ran into `#user-container`.

**For more details, see** http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/ -- scroll about 1/4 of the way down the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an overflow to #message-container because that's the div that's being pushed by the float not its children. #message-box and #text-box don't interact with their parents previous siblings.

So, remove all overflow: auto; and do this:

```
#message-container {
  height: 32em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is a Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ljqmjzkp/1/

PS: Cleaned the code so it's easier to read, also I indented it according to your DOM so you can see the structure. Keep that in mind, it helps ^^